# Jquery Autocomplete Results With Links - Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I have an auto-complete feature on my app. The auto-complete works fine, typing gives me the correct results. However, I want these results to be links that are clickable in addition to simply populating the search box.

Product controller:

```
def index
 @products = Product.where("title like ?", "%#{params[:title]}%")
  respond_to do |format|
    format .js
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json {  render json: @products.map(&:id) }
  end
end
```

Coffee script:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search').autocomplete
  source: $('#search').data('autocomplete-source')
```

View:

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], data: {autocomplete_source: products_path(id: 'product.id') } %>
```

So I guess somewhere I need to pass the id in the JSON and then get the Jquery to show that id as I link, but I don't know how. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the JSON response?

Comment: Here's a sample: `<input data-autocomplete-source="[&quot;007: Blood Stone &quot;,&quot;2000AD&quot;,&quot;AV8B Harrier Assault&quot;]" id="search" name="search" type="text" />` 

Thanks.